# Differentiate between onFocus triggered by mouse-click and by tab-key

Tags: javascript, html

How can one differentiate between an onFocus-event caused by a <kbd>Tab</kbd>-press and one by mouseclick? My goal is to select all of the text in a field when it's tabbed to, but not when it's clicked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I detect the source of a focus? (Javascript, jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888456/can-i-detect-the-source-of-a-focus-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Woah. That new banner is *really* obnoxious.

Comment: Maybe that the click event isn't firing on one case?