# Differentiate between focusin and click JQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, focus

So I've been struggling with this for a while now. I have a list of inputs, and focus and click events should update a selection based on the clicked/focused inputs. I use JQuery for this.

```
<body>
    <input id="d1" type="text" value="a">
    <input id="d2" type="text" value="few">
    <input id="d3" type="text" value="words">
</body>
```

**What I want**

- When I click an input, a selection should be cleared (if CTRL is *not* pressed), and the clicked input should be added to the selection.
- When I input in an input, same as above, but clear the selection always
- When I traverse through the inputs with TAB, the selection should be cleared, and the currently focused input should be added to the selection.

**What I tried**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var stuff = {};

    $(document).ready(function () {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            var selector = "#d" + i;
            $(selector).on({
                "focusin": function(event) { 
                    stuff = {}; 
                    stuff[selector] = true;
                },
                "click": function(event) { 
                    if (!event.ctrlKey) { 
                        stuff = {};
                    } 
                    stuff[selector] = true;
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

However, the `click` causes a `focusin`, so the selection is always cleared. So I tried to get the `ctrlKey` from the `focusin` event, but only MouseEvents have an `ctrlKey` attribute.

**My question(s)**

Is it possible for a `focusin` event to know if it's followed by a `click` event? Or am I using the wrong listeners?

I've searched on Google for a while, but when I add `focus`, most sites are about focussing an element with jQuery, or check if an element is focused, so unfortunately, that didn't get me any further. I've found this, though, but I couldn't distill an answer from it for myself:

- [Differentiate between onFocus triggered by mouse-click and by tab-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726031/differentiate-between-onfocus-triggered-by-mouse-click-and-by-tab-key)
- [Can I detect the source of a focus? (Javascript, jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888456/can-i-detect-the-source-of-a-focus-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

since the focus event always fires, there seems to be no out of the box way to distinct between "focus only" and "focus followed by click" events

but you can make use of this, with simplifying your different steps.
step 1:
since the focus event is always fired first, the selection deletion and updating with the current value is done here.
step 2: since a click event with the ctrl condition met, could happen afterwards, we backup the selection data, before deleting them
step 3: the click event either restores the backed up selection in the ctrl condition, or just deletes the backup. (since it already got updated in the focus event)

in code this means:

```
var stuff = {};    //empty global stuff object
var oldStuff = {}; //empty global backup object

$('input').on({
  "focusin": function (event) {
    oldstuff = stuff; // backup your stuff
    stuff = {};       // delete your stuff
    stuff[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();  // get the current value
    console.log("focussed stuff");
    console.log(stuff); // show it in console
  },
  "click": function (event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey) { // if ctrl key was used
        $.extend(stuff, oldstuff); // merge oldstuff back into stuff
    } else if (!event.ctrlKey) {
        oldstuff = {};  // else delete oldstuff
    }
    console.log("clicked stuff");
    console.log(stuff); // show stuff
  }
});
```

see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eL19p27L/2/

the change event is missing here - but i hope, you get the point, of how i would do it ;)